# Specflow - test work when 'run test' but fails when 'debug'

Tags: selenium, specflow

I have a test in specflow which when run in  'run test' mode works, but when run in 'debug' mode it fails.

The issue given is a selenium webdriver issue:

OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException: Timed out after 60 seconds ---> OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element
  (Session info: chrome=48.0.2564.97)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.14.313457 (3d645c400edf2e2c500566c9aa096063e707c9cf),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)

Please advise what the issue might be.

Many Thanks,
Rahul Dixit

Comment: Could you provide code?

Comment: public static bool  WaitForDisplayed(this IWebDriver driver, By selector)
        {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
            
              return wait.Until((d) => d.FindElement(selector).Displayed);
        
            
        } It fails on the wait

Comment: Are you using NUnit test adapter to run test inside Visual Studio? If so, do you choose "Debug" in the list box in the toolbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a while this issue went away, dont know what was at the bottom of it. Thanks.